# Test every arrangement of variables without hard coding

Tags: python, variables

I have 9 different variables, we will call them a - i, I want to test if 
`a+b+c == d+e+f & a+b+c == g+h+i & a+b+c == a+d+g & a+b+c == b+e+h & a+b+c == c+f+i & a+b+c == a+e+i & a+b+c == c+e+g`. But there is one problem. I want to test all the possible arrangements of this such as swapping b and h or even more variables. I have also calculated that there are 45360 different arrangements. I am wondering if there is any possible way to do this... I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Yes, put your objects into a *container* and use `itertools` or your own algorithm to get the combinatinos you need. Don't use a bunch of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to generate the list of all permutations, then you can either sum them, or write your own custom add function:

```
def add3(n1, n2, n3):
    return n1+n2+n3

list_of_nums = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
all_perm_sums = (add3(n1, n2, n3) for n1, n2, n3 in itertools.permutations(list_of_nums, 3))
all_perm_sums_are_equal = len(set(all_perm_sums)) == 1
```

Hint: be careful with floating points, as floating point additions are not commutative, `a+b` is not necessarily equal to `b+a`, and they're not associative, `(a+b)+c` is not necessarily equal to `a+(b+c)`. This shouldn't be an issue if all the numbers are integers.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question. I guess I worded it slightly wrong. If a=2, b=7, c=6, d=9, e=5, f=1, g=4, h=3, i=8, it should return true because `a+b+c == d+e+f & a+b+c == g+h+i & a+b+c == a+d+g & a+b+c == b+e+h & a+b+c == c+f+i & a+b+c == a+e+i & a+b+c == c+e+g`, even though `a+b+d == c+e+f & a+b+d == g+h+i & a+b+d == a+c+g & a+b+d == b+e+h & a+b+d == d+f+i & a+b+d == a+e+i & a+b+d == d+e+g` is not true. (On the second system of equations I only swapped c with d)